# Angular ternary with expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code inside a directive:

```
<my-object my-attribute="{{ vm.myEval ? '{{vm.variable | lowercase}}' : '{{vm.mytext}}' }}"></my-object>
```

But its returning an error, which probably is because of the expression inside an expression way this is written.

How can I make something like this work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `true ?` hoping to check? What error message are you getting?

Comment: @doldt its not really relevant to this context, but I've changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need single quotes and use round brackets:

```
{{ vm.myEval ? ({{vm.variable | lowercase}}) : ({{vm.mytext}}) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!